# javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Invalid configuration: Not a dbNaming URL

Tags: java, jms, ems

I am using a tibco jms server.

I wanted to create initial contex to tibco jms from java. The code is below:

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
    props.put("java.naming.provider.url", "tcp://myhostname:myport");
    props.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "ContextFactory");
    Context context = null;
    try {
        context = new InitialContext(props);
    } catch (NamingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

But the exception is raised:

```
javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Invalid configuration: Not a dbNaming URL: tcp://myhostname:myport
```

if I look at ems administration tool, there I enter the command

`show factory` and I see the url, which I told above.

Why I got this exception?

Comment: did you try the ip address instead myhostname in your url?

Comment: yes, I tried to type the tcp://localhost:port.